# Get innerHTML from selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following `div`s in an HTML page:

```
<div class="foo">Bar</div>
<div class="foo">Baz</div>
```

I'd like to get an array with the text contained in the two `div`s:

```
['Bar', 'Baz']
```

I can do this using `d3.nodes` but it seems a bit clunky. Is there a smarter way?

```
d3.selectAll(".foo").nodes().map(function(d) { return d.innerHTML; });
```

The answer could be pure Javascript, of course!

Comment: Of the options, I like your way the best.

Comment: I second the above comment. Your code is better than all provided answers.

Comment: The only thing I'd change is making it `map(d => d.textContent)` because you're clearly not interested in getting full, stringified HTML child content, you just want the text in those divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure JS we can achieve this pretty easily by using an array map, which is conveniently built into the [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#syntax) function:

```js
const text = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll(".foo"),
  e => e.textContent
);

console.log(text);
```

```html
<div class="foo">Bar</div>
<div class="foo">Baz</div>
```

Of course, this does require turning the query's static NodeList (which supports `forEach`, but not `map`) into a real Array, but that's typically what you want anyway.

Comment: And as you already mentioned in the comment, `Array.from` can also do the job of `map` for free without creating an intermediate array.

Comment: No it can't, `Array.from` can only create a new Array off of an existing iterable, so we're still going to need that `map` to actually get the textContent out of each element. That said, `Array.from` and `[...iterable]` do (for practical purposes) the same thing so you can use either of those, but you still need `.map(...)` after turning the iterable into an array.

Comment: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".foo"), e => e.textContent)`. Sorry, I misinterpreted what you were getting at in the original comment.

Comment: This is definitely what I was looking for all those years ago. It's not clear to me why `querySelectorAll` doesn't already return an array with `.map` but maybe that's best left for another question. Although a bit of context on this would really help this answer be perfect!

Comment: @Ry- ah, right, completely blanked on the second argument to `from`. Let me update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
var text = [];
document.querySelectorAll(".foo").forEach(function(e){
    text.push(e.textContent);
});
```

Comment: This is really silly. Just use `[...document.querySelectorAll(".foo")].map`? (or `Array.from` if you're fine with that verbosity).

Comment: Not tempted to post a full answer @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans? Looks like your answer would be modern, clear and concise so I could accept it after many years without this question having a definitive answer.

Comment: sure, thusly posted.

Answer (score 3):

Given a few comments to the original post, this seems to be the slickest way (so far!).

Using [`selection.nodes()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_nodes) gets you access to the DOM elements behind the selection:

```
var fooDivs = d3.selectAll(".foo").nodes()
```

You can now use this to get any HTML/CSS property your heart desires, by using the native JavaScript [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
fooDivs.map(function(d) { 
    return d.innerHTML;
});
```

Or, for those who love one-liners:

```
d3.selectAll(".foo").nodes().map(function(d) { return d.innerHTML; });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easily possible with vanilla JavaScript (ES6):

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.foo')

let texts = []

for(let element of elements) {
    texts.push(element.innerText.toLowerCase())
}

console.log(texts)
```

This outputs `["bar", "baz"]`, as can be seen [here](http://jsbin.com/kibacipeco/edit?html,js,console,output).

[ES5 version](http://jsbin.com/vogasimome/1/edit?html,js,console,output):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.foo')

var texts = []

elements.forEach(function(element) {
    texts.push(element.innerText.toLowerCase())
})

console.log(texts)
```

Comment: Well spotted on the `toLowerCase` issue! That was just a typo on my part though!

Answer (score 0):

This question have very simple answer, you have to use `d3.selectAll()` and `text` function like below:

```
var array=[];
d3.selectAll(".foo").each(function(d,i){
   array.push(d3.select(this).text());
});
```